# How to resize root partition (/) without LVM

Tags: partitioning, lubuntu

I am using `Ubuntu 19.04` right now, and I have a `/` and `/home` partition created on my laptop. I didn't set up LVM during installation. Now my `/` partition is running low on space, and I'd like to transfer some of space from `/home` to it.

1. Both have `Ext4` format, and `/` (`/dev/nvme0n1p10`) is located right before `/home`(`/dev/nvme0n1p11`).
2. I have a Windows 10 installed too, `/dev/nvme0n1p3` for `C` and `/dev/nvme0n1p4` for `D`
3. I also have a `/boot` partition (`/dev/nvme0n1p8`) and a `swap` partition (`/dev/nvme0n1p9`)

So how can I do that?
Many thanks.
[image]

Comment: Edit your question with a screenshot of `gparted`, and I'll take a look for you.

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 support ended on January 23, 2020.  Please install a supported version. What size is / as if separate /home, your / should not need to be large. I make partition 25 or 30GB and use about 8GB on new 20.04 and after two years 18.04 was up to about 12GB. But I regularly houseclean.

Comment: 19.04 is not supported here for it has reached the End Of Life as per https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases  Our ability to support you is limited to answering upgrade-related issues.

Comment: Hey @heynnema, I just added a screenshot.

Comment: Without LVM you first need to make a free space after the partition which you want to expand. You can achieve this by deleting/moving/shrinking partitions. All these operations have to be performed on unmounted partitions so at least in some parts you will need to boot a live Linux (eg. from USB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a **swapoff** on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a **swapon** on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- start `gparted`
- **resize** (reduce) the right side of p11 by the amount that you wish to add to p10 (~10G)
- **move** the p11 partition all the way right
- **resize** the right side of p10 all the way right
- click the Apply icon

Comment: After doing the above, there is 1MB space that is unallocated. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: It sits between p10 and p11

Comment: @DrizzleX No. That's used to align partitions.

Comment: Just curious, in what situation shoud I run swapoff in Live CD mode? There is no swap in that mode, right? I ran free -h and swap is 0

Comment: @DrizzleX swapoff won't make any difference, as you're not moving/resizing swap anyway. But... if you see a key icon next to it, it's live.

Comment: Thanks, I have successfully resized my partitions. Great answer